# International Passport data page

Tags: legal, asia

What is the meaning of International Passport data page

Please explain .

Answer (score 4):

The passport data page is the information page in your passport, which contains your photo and personal details such as your name, date of birth, nationality, etc.

This page is traditionally located at the very back of your passport or at the very front.